# Retrieving data within an object in react JS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

```
render() {
        const datamapping = Object.entries(this.state.message);
        console.log(datamapping);
        return (
            //{this.state.message}
            <div>
                <div className="viewall">
                    {datamapping.map((data, key) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={key}>
                                <p>{data}</p>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I have a set of data that looks like this, where typeof = object:

```
{"body", "Items":[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

I want to display it in a table format, but I am unable to access the values inside items. How should I go about doing it? I tried to do a JSON parse, but there was an error. Doing `{data[1]}` gets me to "Items", but I am unable to access the data inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say you have the following parameter:

```
const x = {"body":"test", "Items":[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

now you can access `Items` as follow:

```
const items = x.Items;
```

and extract each element of it as follow:

```
const item0 = items[0];
//or each item inside of each element
const key1 = item0.key1;
const key2 = item0.key2;
```

let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Hi I'm not able to access items as such. Even though typeof returns me an object, the line console.log(datamapping); returns me an array. If I access it as data[1] I get "Items":[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}]

Comment: I have checked it and it works fine on my console.  Did you receive it as an string from backend?

Comment: I sent it over as a JSON string from the backend. I tried to do JSON.parse() but that returned me errors instead

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(this.state.message)); if i do this, i get this error: Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.

Comment: React throws a cross-origin error whenever JSON.parse() receives an invalid string. Check the validity of the JSON value you are storing, since JSON structures are strict about their format. Check that if your stringification works well! I believe you does not receive valide JSON.

Comment: Nice thanks. Do you happen to know if this is valid JSON? {body: "{\"Items\":[{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":"value}],\"Count\":1,\"ScannedCount\":1}"}

Comment: In your `{"body"` section, why this property does not have any value?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a valid JSON, bit I think `body` should be between quotation. You can check the validity in many sites like https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @AudreyWong did my comments help you?